# The model backing context has changed since db was created (two sites same dll error on one)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, console-application

Im getting the following error in a console application

The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using code first migrations blah blah.
Now normally this error is not an issue and I would know how to fix it.

However in this case im building a console app to to a batch process of content in my mvc site im using the dll from my mvc project and the same database as the MVC site to create items in the db. The MVC project is talking to the site no problem but the console app gets the above error.
Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your console app does not have its dbcontext updated. Its tracking the changes and its not up to date with your MVC application. Have this option set on inside:

```
    public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}
```

Then run command in package manager console: Update-database -projectname

Entity framework should now automatically migrate your dbcontext and then run your app without problems.

Comment: will this not make changes to the db that I dont necessarily want as they might cause issues on my main site

Comment: Run add-migration name and then update-database. Also set false automaticmigrarions then. After adding migrations you can see is there any changes. After update you shouldn't see error anymore if update goes well.